# subset data based on condition in r

Tags: r

I want to select those household where all the member's age is greater than 20 in r.

```
 household Members_age
   100          75
   100          74
   100          30
   101          20
   101          50
   101          60
   102          35
   102          40
   102           5
```

Here two household satisfy the condition. Household 100 and 101.
How to do it in r?

what I did is following but it's not working.

```
sqldf("select household,Members_age from data group by household having Members_age > 20")
household Members_age
   100          75
   102          35
```

Please suggest. Here is the sample dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
data <- data.frame(household = c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102),
               Members_age = c(75,74,30,20,50,60,35,40,5))
```

Comment: Household 101 *doesn't* match the condition of all members being greater than 20, it matches all members being greater than or equal to 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave`.

```
data[ave(data$Members_age, data$household, FUN=min) > 20,]
#  household Members_age
#1       100          75
#2       100          74
#3       100          30
```

or only the households.

```
unique(data$household[ave(data$Members_age, data$household, FUN=min) > 20])
#[1] 100
```

Comment: @ GKi Household 101's member's are also greater than 20.

Comment: Household 101 has one member with age=20. I assumed that 20 is not greater than 20. But maybe you want to use `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 2):

I understand SQL's `HAVING` clause, but your request *"all member's age is greater than 20"* does not match your `sqldf` output. This is because `HAVING` is really only looking at the first row for each household, which is why we see 102 (and shouldn't) and we don't see 101 (shouldn't as well).

I suggest to implement your logic, you would change your `sqldf` code to the following:

```r
sqldf("select household,Members_age from data group by household having min(Members_age) > 20")
#   household Members_age
# 1       100          30
```

which is effectively the SQL analog of GKi's `ave` answer.

An alternative:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  filter(all(Members_age > 20)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   household Members_age
#       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1       100          75
# 2       100          74
# 3       100          30
```

and if you just need one row per household, then add `%>% distinct(household)` or perhaps `%>% distinct(household, .keep_all = TRUE)`.

But for base R, I think nothing is likely to be better than GKi's use of `ave`.