# Subset data in r based on two different condition at a time

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to select all those households where the occupants age group are below 15 and between 30 to 40 from the below data frame. Basically I am looking for households with kids along with their parents

```
household Members_age
   100          75
   100          74
   100          30
   101          20
   101          50
   101          60
   102          35
   102          40
   102           5
```

Here only Household 102 satisfy the condition.

I got hint over here [subset data based on condition in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164385/subset-data-based-on-condition-in-r/69164418#69164418)
but not able to add the 2nd condition to filter i.e. age between 30 - 40

Sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
data <- data.frame(household = c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102),
           Members_age = c(75,74,30,20,50,60,35,40,5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` household and look for groups (households) that have both at least one age < 15 and at least one age between 30 and 40.

```
data %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  filter(any(Members_age < 15) & any(between(Members_age, 30, 40))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(household)
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
# household
# <dbl>
#   1       102
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[Members_age < 15 | (Members_age > 30 & Members_age < 40)]
#    household Members_age
# 1:       102          35
# 2:       102           5
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
subset(data, Members_age < 15 | (Members_age >30 & Members_age < 40))
```

-output

```
 household Members_age
7       102          35
9       102           5
```

According to the OP's post `Here only Household 102 satisfy the condition.`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  filter(Members_age < 15 | (Members_age > 30 & Members_age < 40))
```